# Spring bean scope ''prototype" and scheduled method memory leak

Tags: java, spring, memory-leaks

```
    @Component
    @Scope("prototype")
    public class MessageHandller {
      .........................
     private static ConcurrentMap<String, Boolean> someObjectList = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); 
      ....................................
       @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "60000")
       public static void doSomething() {
          if(***) {
             someObjectList.add(**);
          } else {
             someObjectList.remove(**);
          }

       }
    }
```

So let say I have Class MessageHandller  which is Spring Bean with Scope of Prototype. In this Class I have Scheduled method "doSomething" which runs every 60000 mili seconds.

I think Scheduled method may cause memory leak, because it will always hold refference to MessageHandler class which is "prototype" scope, which means GC will never collect it? Can someone explain if I'am wrong?

Comment: it wont. unused objects will be eligble for gc

Comment: Have you find the solution? I'm also having trouble releasing prototype bean due to the scheduled method inside.

Answer (score 1):

You must clearly differentiate between the method annotated with @Schedule and the bean itself , when you annotate you method and you enable schedule feature through @EnableScheduling or xml alternative, the spring will lookup and search annotated method withing managed bean (annotated with @Compenont, @Service ... ) as the mention in [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html)

If you read about bean processor ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor. you'll notice that scope it not involved in the process , and that the method w'll be invoked by `TaskScheduler` regardless the scope of bean parent

Now for prototype bean the documentation mention that :

> In contrast to the other scopes, Spring does not manage the complete lifecycle of a prototype bean: the container instantiates, configures, and otherwise assembles a prototype object, and hands it to the client, with no further record of that prototype instance. Thus, although initialization lifecycle callback methods are called on all objects regardless of scope, in the case of prototypes, configured destruction lifecycle callbacks are not called. The client code must clean up prototype-scoped objects and release expensive resources that the prototype bean(s) are holding

So when no reference to prototype object it w'll be destroyed by garbage collector implicitly  like any `new object()`

To make it clear the life cycle of the behaviour of the schedule method is different from the bean which is declared because its implementation is used by other bean manager by spring like any of `TaskScheduler`  implementation for that purpose,

Cheers